# How compiling -static ncursesw in Fedora

Tags: c, mouse, fedora, ncurses

My program compiles on Debian, but Fedora has another package named `ncurses-static`. I compile:

```
$gcc -std=c99 -static moje.o pliki.o -o static_file -lncursesw -ltinfo
```

I get 2 errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libncursesw.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `enable_gpm_mouse':
```

and

```
undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

How can I compile a static program with `ncursesw` in **Fedora**?

I can't compile `ncurses` itself I would do it in normal Fedora system.

Comment: Can you just link to ˋdlˋ (ˋ-ldlˋ)?

Comment: I do this. And prewiously showing what I get  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libncursesw.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `load_gpm_library':
(.text+0x5b8): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking (who deleting my comment i dont know)